# jqueryui dialog missing title bar, "x button" and surround dialog box

Tags: javascript, css, jquery-ui, dialog

I assume this is a CSS error.  I downloaded the jqueryui dialog example code, (which displays as advertised in the jquery site) store it in notepad and point to it with various browsers, but the styling is wrong.   There is no title bar, there is no X button, however the title text does appear and a button labeled "close" appears.   There is no surrounding box either.  Looks like the text and close button are sitting on top of the existing content.   Is is draggable,close button works, so functionality is ok.

Here is the code take from the jqueryui site.

```html
   <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <title>jQuery UI Dialog - Default functionality</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
      <script>
      $( function() {
        $( "#dialog" ).dialog();
      } );
      </script>
    </head>
    <body>
     
    <div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
      <p>This is the default dialog which is useful for displaying information. The dialog window can be moved, resized and closed with the 'x' icon.</p>
    </div>
     
     
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The X button is showing fine here, if you'r using jquery ui locally you must add images folder

Comment: if you downloaded the archive from the official website you'll find images folder https://jqueryui.com/download/all/ if you copied it already check your path

Comment: That makes sense. I don't understand  what   <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css"> is pointed to,  isn't that a local file?  If so, why would it work for you?   I'm not much of a  jquery person obviously.

Comment: your code is working look here https://jsfiddle.net/vopw2wv4/ , what do you mean by that makes no sense ! the problem is clear the icon image is not loading

Comment: I said it makes sense.   My question would be, how does a browser go about resolving image references? I've installed many versions of jqueryui in the process solving this.

Comment: sorry, see your console in developer tools and tell me it should give you errors